# Boost threads - passing parameters by reference

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread, boost-bind

My application has a section that resembles the following code

```
void SomeClass::OtherMethod(std::vector<std::string>& g)
{
  g.pushback("Something");
}

void SomeClass::SomeMethod()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  boost::thread t(boost::bind(&SomeClass::OtherMethod,this,v)
  t.join();
  std::cout << v[0]; //Why is this empty when the vector created on stack
}
```

I wanted to know why the vector v is empty when the vector is created on the stack and it works when it is created on the heap. I was expecting the above code to work since the vector remains in scope even when it is created on the stack.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Bind` copies its parameters. Use `boost::ref`:

```
boost::thread t(boost::bind(&SomeClass::OtherMethod,this, boost::ref(v))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I still dont get it. If bind copies its parameter how does that make a difference. Sorry I am confused here

Comment: @MistyD Now it copies a `reference_wrapper`, which takes its argument (i.e. your vector) by reference and provides implicit `T&` type-cast operator.

Comment: I understand that `boost::ref` will do the trick. I am just curious why it doesnt work without it. You stated that without using boost::ref it will make a copy. I am just curious about the fact that even if it makes a copy why doesnt it work ?

Comment: @MistyD Because `OtherMethod` takes by reference a *copy* of the original vector and changes it. The original vector remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

A thread by default takes arguments by value, even if the function itself expects a reference. Use boost::ref() to force passing argument by reference.

> () by default the arguments are copied into internal storage, where
>   they can be accessed by the newly created thread of execution, even if
>   the corresponding parameter in the function is expecting a reference.

A. Williams, "Concurrency in Action", 2.2 Passing arguments to a thread function.