# Visual Studio 2010 OpenCV Multithread Mat does not copy to another Mat

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Good afternoon to all!

I've been using Visual Studio 2010 with OpenCV to develop a code for Face recognition. I'm trying to reach the task by two Threads (I need to do it this way, because i´m going to apply it on a bigger project), one (the main) to show the frames and the second to capture (from the Webcam of my laptop) and store the frames on a Mat object (Fast Capture).

The inconvenient here is that the second Thread is capturing the frames, but the main is not showing them. I think there is a problem with copying the Mat from the capture Thread to the Mat on the main thread ("current_frame" seems to be empty after I do the assignation)

Here is the code (I'm using Boost::Thread for Multithreading)

New code with suggestions

Global declarations

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <boost\thread.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
 #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 boost::mutex mtx;
```

The function

```
void camCapture(VideoCapture& cap, Mat& frame, bool* Capture)

{  
while (*Capture==true) 
{
mtx.lock();
cap >> frame;
mtx.unlock();
if(frame.empty())
{
    cout<<"No hay captura"<<endl;
}
else
{
    cout<<"Frame capturado"<<endl;
}
}cout << "camCapture finished\n";
return;}
```

The main

```
int main() {
try{
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
Mat frame,current_frame, SFI, Input;
bool *Capture = new bool;
*Capture = true;
if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;  
//your capture thread has started
boost::thread captureThread(camCapture, cap, frame, Capture);   
while(1)
{
    if(frame.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Frame en hilo principal vacio"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Frame en hilo principal capturado"<<endl;
    }
    mtx.lock();
    current_frame = frame.clone();
    mtx.unlock();
    if(current_frame.empty())
    {
        cout<<"Current_Frame vacio"<<endl;
    }
    else{
    imshow("Streaming",current_frame);
    if(waitKey(10)==27)break;           
    }       
}
//Terminate the thread
captureThread.join();
}   
catch(Exception & e)
{
    cout<<e.what()<<endl;
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: there are multiple problems. 1. you HAVE TO pass "frame" by reference to the function, otherwise you will just update a local variable (might still work if Mat header shares the data but very error-prone). 2. you have to lock the mutex around cap >> frame, too. 3. on the main lock the mutex only around .clone() line to not block during uncritical code.

Comment: 4. does your thread call camCapture in a loop? it looks like your thread captures only one image and returns afterwards 5. not sure whether cap has to be passed by reference too (I dont know the behaviour of copied VideoCapture objects)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'm so new in this and i don't understand so many things, I made the changes like this, 1. On the function, pass by reference the objects "frame"and "cap", void camCapture(VideoCapture &cap, Mat& frame, bool* Capture). 2. mtx.lock(); cap>>frame; mtx.unlock(); 3.mtx.lock(); current_image=frame.clone(); mtx.unlock();

Comment: 4.No, it doesn't, I understand that when I call boost::thread captureThread(camCapture, cap, frame, Capture), the function camcapture starts to capture frames indefinitely (until the bool variable Capture changes to false). do i have to put the call to the capturethread in the while loop?, because if i do that i would have to put in captureThread.join() too. I made the first 3 changes and the Mat object "current_image" still empty when i tested with the if(current_frame.empty()). Again, thanks for your help.

Comment: What i'm looking for is to create a thread to capture frames continuously and stores it on the same frame, then, when the main thread requieres a frame, it will get the newest frame and not the oldest on the buffer.(Eliminates the lag when the application stars, i think)

Comment: but you do get console outputs continuously like "Frame capturado" "Frame capturado" "Frame capturado"? Can you add a cout in the main loop that prints for example the current image reslution if image isnt empty?

Comment: how did you pass the mutex to the thread?

Comment: Yes, in fact, the output i obtain on the console is a continuously "Frame capturado" "Current_frame_vacio" "Frame capturado" "Current_frame_vacio" ... is it really neccesary to lock the mutex on the camCapture function?,the mutex on the main function doesn´t lock both threads when i call it? do i have to pass the mutex as a parameter to the function camCapture,? because i just call it on the function (i declare the mutex as a global variable). Thanks help.

Comment: yes you have to lock it in each place where you want to access the memory that you want to secure (the variable "frame"). Global variable is ok for now. Can you add a cout in the main loop where you print whether variable "frame" is empty or not?

Comment: I just add it an if condition just before the while loop and on the while loop, if (current_frame.empty()){cout<<"Frame on main thread empty"<<endl; else {cout<<"Frame on main thread capture"<<endl;}} ... i run it, and the console shows the msg "Frame on main thread empty" ... it's like the variable were different to the variable on the function camCapture ... I will upload the code with your suggestions, maybe I´m doing something wrong...

Comment: I'm currently downloading boost to test it, but this will take some time...

Comment: Ok Micka, i really appreciate the time that you are taking to help me...I already actualize the code on the question...so you can see the changes i already did...

Comment: Looks like boost thread binding doesn't work with "passed by reference" variables, you might have to use pointers instead. I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [Boost threads - passing parameters by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17219508/boost-threads-passing-parameters-by-reference) you have to use `boost::ref(v)` if you want to pass a variable by reference to a boost::thread function. But you could use pointers instead.

In addition you should share the mutex to the thread by passing it as pointer or reference variable instead of using it as global:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

boost::mutex mtx;



void camCapture(VideoCapture& cap, Mat& frame, bool* Capture)
{
    while (*Capture == true)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        cap >> frame;
        mtx.unlock();
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            cout << "No hay captura" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Frame capturado" << endl;
        }

    }cout << "camCapture finished\n";

    return;
}

int main() {

    try{
        VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
        Mat frame, current_frame, SFI, Input;
        bool *Capture = new bool; // better not use a pointer here, but use a bool and pass the address or by reference.
        *Capture = true;
        if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
            return -1;
        //your capture thread has started
        boost::thread captureThread(camCapture, boost::ref(cap), boost::ref(frame), Capture);
        while (1)
        {
            mtx.lock();
            current_frame = frame.clone();
            mtx.unlock();

            if (current_frame.empty())
            {
                cout << "Current_Frame vacio" << endl;
            }
            else{
                imshow("Streaming", current_frame);
                if (waitKey(10) == 27)
                {
                    // TODO: you should use a mutex (or an atomic type) here, too, maybe setting a bool is thread-safe, but this can't be guaranteed for each hardware!
                    *Capture = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //Terminate the thread
        captureThread.join();

        // give memory free:
        delete Capture;
    }
    catch (Exception & e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: God Bless you Micka !... It works perfectly ... Thanks a lot for your help and time ... i declare the mutex on the main, and pass it by reference on the camCapture function (adding the parameter boost::mutex& mtx. And when i call it on the main as a parameter, boost::ref(mtx)) ... also i modify every variable in which i was using reference (cap and frame) and add it boost::ref, just like you said...